# How to compress base64 decoded video data using ffmpeg in django

Tags: python, django, ffmpeg, django-channels

I want to upload the video/audio file in my **django-channels** project. So I uploaded video(**base64 encoded url**) from websocket connection. It is working fine. But now after decoding base64 video data I want to compress that video using **ffmpeg**.But it showing error like this.
''**Raw: No such file or directory**''
I used '**AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer**' in consumers.py file.Here is my code:
consumers.py:

```
async def send_file_to_room(self, room_id, dataUrl, filename):
        # decoding base64 data
        format, datastr = dataUrl.split(';base64,')
        ext = format.split('/')[-1]
        file = ContentFile(base64.b64decode(datastr), name=filename)
        print(f'file: {file}')
        # It prints 'Raw content'
        output_file_name = filename + '_temp.' + ext
        ff = f'ffmpeg -i {file} -vf "scale=iw/5:ih/5" {output_file_name}'
        subprocess.run(ff,shell=True)
```

May be here ffmpeg can not recognize the file to be compressed. I also tried to solve this using **post_save** signal.

signals.py:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=ChatRoomMessage)
def compress_video_or_audio(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print("Inside signal")
    if created:
        if instance.id is None:
            print("Instance is not present")
        else:
            video_full_path = f'{instance.document.path}'
            print(video_full_path)
   // E:\..\..\..\Personal Chat Room\media\PersonalChatRoom\file\VID_20181219_134306_w5ow8F7.mp4
            output_file_name = filename + '_temp.' + extension
            ff = f'ffmpeg -i {filename} -vf "scale=iw/5:ih/5" {output_file_name}'
            subprocess.run(ff,shell=True)
            instance.document = output_file_name
            instance.save()
```

It is also causing **"E:..\Django\New_Projects\Personal: No such file or directory"**.
How can I solve this issue? Any suggetions.It will be more helpful if it can be compressed before saving the object in database. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the file system. Is the file located there?

Comment: In case of post_save signal it exists because object is saved allready.

Comment: And you can see the file? The error says that it can't find the file so it's important to check that the file really exists in the file system where you expected it to be saved

Comment: yes file is saved there in exact location. I checked it manually. I think problem is in the path to find out the file.

Comment: It means then that it isn't saved in the path that is stored in the DB. So it's probably an issue of how you specified the path in the model. Post your model code

Comment: I have solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some struggle I haved solved the problem here. I don't know either it is a good solution or not but for me it has worked. I have used post_save signal here. So file has been saved allready. I tried **instance.document.path** first to pass the file path to ffmpeg. But ffmpeg can not recognize the file.

```
video_full_path = f'{instance.document.path}'
print(video_full_path)
# E:\..\..\..\Personal Chat Room\media\PersonalChatRoom\file\VID_20181219_134306_w5ow8F7.mp4
```

And the error was:

```
"E:..\Django\New_Projects\Personal: No such file or directory"
```

I think it is because of the space inside 'Personal Chat Room'. Later I tried with

```
media_in = instance.document.url
print(media_in)
# /media/PersonalChatRoom-2/file/VID_20181219_134306_jS7H8fL.mp4
```

Still ffmpeg could not recognize the file inside media.
The trick has worked for me is:

```
media_in = '.' + instance.document.url
print(media_in)
# ./media/PersonalChatRoom-2/file/VID_20181219_134306_jS7H8fL.mp4
filename, extension = os.path.splitext(media_in)
media_out = filename + '_temp' + extension
print(media_out)
# ./media/PersonalChatRoom-2/file/VID_20181219_134306_jS7H8fL_temp.mp4
subprocess.run('ffmpeg -i ' + media_in + ' -vf "scale=iw/4:ih/4" ' +  media_out,  shell=True)
```

Now this time ffmpeg recognized the file and output is saved in the media/.
Next problem I had faced that,

```
instance.document = media_out
instance.save()
print(instance.document.url)
# /media/media/PersonalChatRoom-1/file/VID_20181219_134306_jS7H8fL_temp.mp4
```

browser is not able to find out the file from the location because after saving extra
'/media/' has added with the path.
To solve this,

```
output_file_name = media_out.split('./media/')[-1]
print(output_file_name)
# PersonalChatRoom-1/file/VID_20181219_134306_jS7H8fL_temp.mp4
...
...
instance.document = output_file_name
instance.save()
```

This time it works perfectly.

Full code: signals.py:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

import os
import subprocess

from chat.models import ChatRoomMessage

@receiver(post_save, sender=ChatRoomMessage)
def compress_video_or_audio(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.id is None:
            print("Instance is not present")
        else:
            media_in = '.' + instance.document.url
            filename, extension = os.path.splitext(media_in)
            media_out = filename + '_temp' + extension
            output_file_name = media_out.split('./media/')[-1]
            subprocess.run('ffmpeg -i ' + media_in + ' -vf "scale=iw/4:ih/4" ' +  media_out, shell=True)
            instance.document = output_file_name
            instance.save()
```

The answer is given here, to compress the video file after saving object(still don't know how to do it before saving).So there are two video files created inside media folder for each object. The object.document.url is referencing 2nd one now. So, first one can be deleted later.